# One data in two table

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm new in web developing and I have question. I've two tables `product` and `slider` and when I want to upload picture in `product` I'm using `<form></form>` and in form I've input like : `<input type="file" name='photo'` photo uploading by `name`. But now I want to `@if slider mode == 1` this picture also must be uploaded in `slider` table, condition I have done. So my question is there any way to upload data in two different table from one `form` or are other best ways to implement this?

Comment: Just run another query to insert into the other table when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Can you give me one example, how?

Comment: yes, all data will be sent to Controller action, and there u can do whatever u want

Comment: Oh I guess thank you